# Cardview shadow appearing in Android Studio but not on device in Marshmallow

Tags: android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, shadow, android-cardview

I have set `elevation` as well as compatPadding
Device has Marshmallow

In android preview, shadow is visible, but when launched on device, then shadow does not appear anywhere

Comment: Try by setting margin to your view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your manifest file has a `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` line, delete it.

Comment: Worked and even added a shadow to existing buttons!